# Svelte 5 - using $state for class field in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-5

I have a class:

```js
class TestClass {
    prop = $state('test');
}
```

It works in `.svelte.js` and `.svelte` files with `<script lang="js">`, but doesn't work in `.svelte.ts` and `.svelte` files with `<script lang="ts">`.
Getting this error:

> CompileError: $state(...) can only be used as a variable declaration initializer or a class field

Am I doing anything wrong or Svelte 5 just doesn't support TS class field states yet?

My `tsconfig.json` file content:

```
{
  "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "target": "es2019",
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "paths": {
      ....
    }
  },
  "include": [
    ....
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a TS configuration that specifies a [`target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) (or uses the default) which causes the class to be [compiled down to a function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8BQ0-QAcAnAewOgF5oASZMJeACgHIHlmBKAbmwF9tsAE3igwReNABmAVwB2wJAEsSsmnQYAeWAD5GANzAhp8AFxwOZ2DyA) for compatibility with < ES6 or the class field initializers may be turned into constructor assignments.

Hence you have to make sure the target is at least `"es6"` or `"es2015"` and if the target is lower than `"es2022"` then [`useDefineForClassFields`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields) has to be set to `true` (see documentation and notes on default value).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have `"target": "es2019"` in the tsconfig. Added almost full config to the question

Comment: How is the TS built and pre-processed in the components?

Comment: in svelte.config.js `preprocess: [vitePreprocess()],` from `@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte`; 
in vite.config.ts `plugins: [sveltekit()]`
that's it I guess, nothing special anymore

Comment: @StanislauListratsenka The assignment gets moved to the constructor, see amended answer.